# @Value not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using the mvc Editor features but it seems that the @something doesn't work. I don't know why.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { @Value = "xxx" })
```

This take the model value and not the "xxx".

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Why are you adding an @ before `Value`? Remove it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the @ in front of Value. As you have it already in front of Html. Remove it and it should work.

Comment: Nop I always have the model value and not the other with `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { Value = "xxx" })`

Comment: The value used is not "xxx" but the model's (user) value.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the second @. if you want your value to come from model, you have to write something like this,

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { value = Model.Password})
```

In either case you have to remove the second @ before value

Comment: if you want the value of the model to be shown you dont need the new {  value = Model.Password}. @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password) should be enough

Comment: That would be correct. But the use of value would just be unnecessary. i agree the use of 'htmlattributes' does come in handy for other attributes

Answer (score 0):

The `@Value` works for `TextBoxFor` but not `EditorFor` (since it is generic...).